# Loop in twig for form symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I prog one application for my project.

I have one form for Mesure.

for the moment I have this :

[image]

But I want this :

[image]

Have you got a suggestion?

My code is :

MesureType :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
    ->add('date')
    ->add('mesure')
    ->add('stagiaire', EntityType::class, array('class' => 'stbfAdministratifBundle:Stagiaire',
    'choice_label' => function($allChoices, $currentChoiceKey)
    {
        return $allChoices->getNom().' '.$allChoices->getPrenom();
    }
    ,'multiple' => false));
    $builder->add('enregistrer', SubmitType::class);
}
```

My controler :

```
public function ajouterAction(Request $request)
    {
    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()
                ->getManager()
                ->getRepository('stbfSportifBundle:ParamPhysiologique');

        $params = $repository->findAll();

        $uneMesure = new Mesure();
        $form = $this->get('form.factory')->create(MesureType::class, $uneMesure);


        if ($request->isMethod('POST') && $form->handleRequest($request)->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($uneMesure);
            $em->flush();

        }
        return $this->render('stbfSportifBundle:Mesure:ajouter.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView(), 'param' => $params));
    }
```

And twig :

```
{% block body %}
<h1>Page d'ajout d'une mesure pour un stagiaire</h1>

<table>
<tr>
<td>{{ form_widget(form.date) }}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>{{ form_widget(form.stagiaire) }}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    {% for param in param %}
<td>
    {{param.libelle}} : {{ form_widget(form.mesure) }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
{{ form_widget(form.enregistrer, {'attr': {'class': 'btn btn-primary'}}) }}
{% endblock %}
```

I need you're help, I don't know why my loop don't work.

Thank's for you're help.

Comment: `for param in param`, perhaps you mean `for param in params`?

Comment: no it's for param in param.

Comment: As @Oli said, rename your param variable because you override it in your `for`.

Comment: Have a look to https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html

Comment: Yes but I want to {{param.libelle}} =  {{ form_widget(form.mesure) }}

Comment: Exactly In my database I have param_physiologique (id, code, libelle) I want in my form the libelle of param and input area (mesure)

Comment: But for the moment the input area it just in the first param...

Answer (score 2):

With reference to your code: first of all try to dump your variable `param` if you got all the values then change the loop variable
i.e. try:  `{% for param2 in param %}`

One more thing:
your code is

```
{% block body %}
<h1>Page d'ajout d'une mesure pour un stagiaire</h1>

<table>
<tr>
<td>{{ form_widget(form.date) }}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>{{ form_widget(form.stagiaire) }}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    {% for param in param %}
<td>
    {{param.libelle}} : {{ form_widget(form.mesure) }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
{{ form_widget(form.enregistrer, {'attr': {'class': 'btn btn-primary'}}) }}
{% endblock %}
```

your table structure is not correct. Repeat the  inside the for loop.

Use this:

```
{% for param2 in param %}
<tr>
<td>
    {{param2.libelle}} : {{ form_widget(form.mesure) }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Don't changed the problem

Comment: dump() returns the required data in twig?

Comment: It return param2.libelle but dont make form.mesure correctly. I have just form.mesure in the first libelle but I want in all libelle